# AsnycTask Not Working

Tags: android, android-asynctask

**EDIT**
Okay really simplified version, let's call this my Activity2

```
public class test {
    String username, id;
    TextView view1, view2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        view1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        view2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        new testFunction().execute();

        view1.setText(username);
        view2.setText(id);
     }

     private class testFunction extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

         @Override
         protected Void doInBackground(Void... x) {
             username = "1";
             id = "2";
             return null;
         }
      }
}
```

Activity1 has a submit button that starts Activity2 (this activity). After Activity2 calls onCreate(), "12" will appear on the screen. When I click back (destroy Activity2 and go back to Activity1), AND THEN go back to Activity2 again, nothing appears on the screen. Why is this?

Comment: You also need to understand Activity lifecycle. onCreate is called once during the lifecyle of the Activity unless its destroyed and recreated.

Comment: Why you use ActionBarActivity here... is this actionbar related class

Comment: It's not, it was just added by default.

Comment: change it to "Activity" instead of "ActionBarActivity"

Comment: you have hardcode the values here... can you plz give us a screen shot of your results(before press back and after press back button)

Answer (score 1):

This is one problem

```
new testFunction().execute("1", "2").get();
```

You should not use `get()`. It blocks the ui thread waiting for the result. And you should never block the ui thread. Use

```
new testFunction().execute("1", "2");
```

Declare the variables as instance variables

```
TextView view1,view2;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_data);
     view1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
     view2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
     new testFunction().execute("1", "2")
```

Then in Asynctask onPostExecute update the views

```
@override
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
   super.onPostExecute(result);
   // update view here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I tried this but it still didn't work :/

Comment: @user3369427 this works fine. You understanding of the lifecycle of the Activity is wrong. onCreate is called only once during the lifecycle of the Activity. that's the reason you feel it won't work but actually it works fine and meant to work that way

Comment: Yes I agree with your assessment, that was my feeling of the problem. What happens when I click that back button? Is the activity finished?

Comment: @user3369427 Activities are added to backstack. So Activity1-->Activity2. Activity 2 is at the top, Onback button click Activity2 pops out destroyed. Activity1 takes focus. Activity1 is paused and resumes. Only if android feels it needs memeory it destroyes activity1 and that too according to priority

Comment: @user3369427 read this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: Yes I understand that, so after OnBack button is clicked -> Activity 2 is popped and destroyed and Activity 1 is resumed. So if I click the submit button and go to Activity 2, is onCreate() called for Activity 2?

Comment: So my question still remains, how come it works on the first submit. But when I go back (destroy activity 2, go back to activity 1, and then start activity 2 again) it doesn't work? It should produce the same result as the first time?

Comment: @user3369427 explain clearly what is happening. And what is that you want. It will work no problem. Just make sure you make the above changes

Answer (score 0):

finish the actvity when you have pressed back button like
Intent i = new Intent(this,Here is your class name.Class);

```
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

by this whenever you will go in second act by press submit button that time on create call 
and you can also call your asnyc task in on resume method every time on resume will call.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the username and id value when closing the fragment.
Have a look into Fragment lifecycle onSaveInstanceState.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
outState.putBoolean(ARG_NAME, username);
outState.putBoolean(ARG_ID, id);
```

Comment: I'm not using fragments, but I assume I should still do this?

So this method would be called when I click button, correct? And then this Bundle would be sent to the onCreate method?

Comment: Activities have a lifecycle too, so everytime you activity/fragment gets to the background this method is used to store all data needed to restore exactly that state, when it comes back (e.g. when you change orientation this is what you have to do in order to don't loose any data). The bundle of saved data will be given in the `onCreate` and `onCreateView` as parameter when the fragment gets back to the front.

Answer (score 0):

I have add some code lines to your onCreate method

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_data);

     //get the values from previous avtivity
     Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
     username=bundle.getString("username").toString();
     id=bundle.getString("id").toString();

     String result = new testFunction().execute("1", "2").get();
     TextView view1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     TextView view2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
     view1.setText(username);
     view2.setText(id);
}
```

in order to get the values you must pass the values from previous activity, I guess you have did it correctly, what you missed is, you forgot to get the Intent values and assign them to username,id variables